# How does this while loop help a function when no statements inside the loop

Tags: javascript, function, loops, while-loop, dom-events

how does the while loop works here while we didn't gave any statement inside of it.
I wanted to know how this loop helps to run the `function activeMenu()`.

```
const links = document.querySelectorAll(".nav-item");
const section = document.querySelectorAll("section");

function activeMenu() {
  let len = section.length;
  while (--len && window.scrollY + 97 < section[len].offsetTop) {}
  links.forEach((li) => li.classList.remove("active"));
  links[len].classList.add("active");
  console.log(len);
}
```

Comment: In each iteration `len` decreases. So the loop looks for an appropriate `section[len]`.

Comment: More readable code might be `let len = section.length - 1; while (section[len] && window.scrollY + 97 < section[len].offsetTop) { len--; }`

Comment: @romellem you missed `len>0`

Comment: Using the debugger or some console logging would go a long way to self-answering this question. You can look at the variables used in the `while` expr (even if inside the currently-empty body), or reason about the code by looking at (a) what's being done before the loop, (b) what's used (and done) in the loop, and (c) what's used after the loop. Here `len` looks like a good candidate for examination.